server-side / client-side routing problem on browser reload
I have a MERN app deployed to Heroku.  This is a single page application that has the front-end and back-end in the same repository.
On production, the correct view will display when I navigate to any given page.  However, upon refreshing the browser, all of the text and styling disappears and the app renders the default response from whatever the /api route is.
This is ONLY happening on production.  My understanding is that there is an issue with how server-side routing is interacting with client-side routing.  I assumed that changing the order in which the routes are being set would help, but it hasn't seemed to resolve the problem.
app.ts:
import "dotenv/config";
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import path from "path";
import * as AboutRoutes from "./routes/about";
import * as ResultsRoutes from "./routes/results";
import * as UserRoutes from "./routes/user";
import * as DogsRoutes from "./routes/dogs";

const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");

const origin = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'https://dog-breeds-b3bc9b835a36.herokuapp.com' : 'http://localhost:3000';

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: origin,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
  }),
);

app.use(AboutRoutes.router);
app.use(DogsRoutes.router);
app.use(ResultsRoutes.router);
app.use(UserRoutes.router);

// app.use(express.static(path.resolve('client/build')))
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
};

export default app;


should it be path.join  instead of  path.resolve

That didn't fix it :\
